# How to access the image tag in chrome browser

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, watir, watir-webdriver

I am unable to access the following image tag, could you please help me out.

```
<div class="abc" style="width:350px;height:200px;">
<div id="delete5Content" class="abc" style="width:350px;height:200px;">
<div class="deleteConfirm">
<p>
<p class="text">
<a onclick="return layered();" href="#">
<a onclick="return address.delete('5');" href="#">
<img id="delete5" class="cancelButton" alt="Delete" src="/abc/zyx/clear.gif">
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried various different options

```
browser.img(:id,delete5).click
```

The value appended to delete is dynamic, it keeps on changing and I even tried with

```
browser.img(:id,'/delete/i').click
browser.img(:alt,'Delete').click
browser.image(:src,'/abc/zyx/clear.gif').click
```

Comment: @Justin Ko,I have created the new question with the code mentioned can you please have a look into it in u r free time

Comment: It would help if you could be more specific about what you mean by "unable to access". Is there an exception? The examples `browser.img(:id,delete5).click` and `browser.img(:id,'/delete/i').click` look like they have typos (ie missing/extra quotations), but it is hard to tell if that is just with the question or the actual code.

Comment: yaa it says unable "element not visible"

Comment: There can be a number of reasons why the element is not visible. So that we are not randomly guessing solutions, please provide the HTML/CSS/JavaScript that reproduces the problem.

Comment: irb(main):010:0> @ie.image(:id,'/delete/i').click
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: unable to locate element, using {:tag_
name=>"img", :id=>"/delete/i"}   these is the error I got

Comment: That UnknownObjectException is not the same as the "element not visible" exception. `@ie.image(:id,'/delete/i')` will fail because you are looking for a id that exactly matches `/delete/i`. To do a partial match, it needs to be a regular expression - ie `@ie.image(:id, /delete/i)` (notice the removed quotations). However, that is unlikely to solve the "element not visible" exception.

Comment: I tried using image button it returns true when I used exists? but when I tried to click on it doesn't return any error   irb(main):015:0> @ie.button(:src,'/assets/common/clear.gif').exists?
=> true,same when I used the click no action is happening except the scroll bar scrolls.  irb(main):014:0> @ie.button(:src,'/assets/common/clear.gif').click
=> [ ]  I mean it takes me to the bottom of the page    @Justin Ko

Comment: I tried with the above one without the quotations it still give me the element not visible error @JustinKo

Comment: Sorry, I am having a hard time piecing together your comments. You really need to provide enough information that would allow us to reproduce the problem on our own machines.

Comment: What I was trying to say is that I even tried with the image button through which it returns true that element exists and when I tried to clik on it doesn't retun any error but it takes me to bottom of the page rather than deleting it

Comment: But when I try running those Watir commands against the provided HTML, I can get the JavaScript in the onclick to trigger. That is what I mean by we need more information to be able to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're trying to click on the image. Well, the image is contained inside a link, so you're going to want to click that instead.

Tricky though, it doesn't have many readily available tags to select with. This should work though:

```
css_inside_selector = "return address.delete('5');"
browser.element(:css, "a[onclick=#{css_inside_selector}]").click
```

Let me know if this works for you. I give it about a 60% percent chance of success...

Another way that could work, you select some containing element, then just tell it to grab all the `a` elements and select the second one or whatever it is....

```
browser.p(:class => "text").as[1].click
```